# Why are my hidden communities visible under the 'top', 'reputation' and 'activity' tabs on the Network Profile page?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, network-profile, hidden-communities

Recently, I've discovered that the communities that I have hidden are still visible under the 'top', 'reputation' and 'activity' tabs of my Network Profile.

> https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation

Is this a bug or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)? If so, doesn't this defeat the purpose of hiding a community since it can still be found by navigating to the 'reputation' tab?

Comment: Related: [they also appear in the combined flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254438/would-it-be-useful-to-remove-hidden-communities-from-the-combined-flair)

Comment: And they also appear in your 'top posts' tab: https://stackexchange.com/users/6487005/panda

Comment: @Glorfindel Yea, apparently, it also shows up in the 'activity' tab too.

Comment: "Hiding" was only ever meant to hide it from *casual* eyes on other Q&A sites. Did you read the top of the "Hide Communities" page? It says: "Hiding a community means other users will not see it in your Communities list or Top Network Posts.".

Comment: @Oded Oh I see, but it's still visible under the 'top' tab (Top Network Posts) on the Stack Exchange Network Profile.

Comment: It wasn't intended as a foolproof privacy control. Very specific use case and the network profile was mostly out of it.

Comment: @Oded Ah, just wanted to clarify. Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: Feature request for this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315445/dont-show-hidden-communities-on-top-posts-in-network-profile

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hiding communities is not intended as a foolproof privacy control. It is only meant to hide them from the most casual eyes on Q&A sites.

The top of the page has this:

> Hiding a community means other users will not see it in your Communities list or Top Network Posts.

That is the limit of the promise it makes.

We are also hiding communities in the list of sites on the network profile, again as this is likely something a casual browser might encounter.

This feature has a very specific use case and the network profile was mostly out of it.

Comment: What is the actual use case of this feature? I can't really think of anything, it's not a privacy feature, but I see no other reason to hide communities except privacy.

Comment: @MadScientist - people who don't want a prospective employer/recruiter/colleague who happens on their profile to see that they are active on some specific sites.

Comment: That's a case where this leaky hiding could also backfire and cost me a job, so I wouldn't trust it enough to use it. So having completely separate professional and private accounts is the only way to achieve this properly, but rather annoying.

Comment: It '*works*' too well (peculiarly) since it: 1. Hides it in one place, leaving you under the impression it's hidden. 2. Exposes it elsewhere, when you may not want that. 3. For the topper it hides it in [your combined Flair total](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=flair), where you probably don't want it hidden (subtracted) - since as a 'combined total' it's *hidden* already, without being subtracted.

Comment: The feature description says "*will not see it in [...] Top Network Posts*" but actually my hidden communities *are* visible in my Top Network Posts, even when not logged in. It would be great if you could fix this bug, thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - given that I no longer work at Stack Overflow, I would be hard pressed to fix the bug. I suggest you open a new question here describing the bug.