# Hidden communities aren't that hidden

Tags: bug, profile-page, network-profile

Following up on a discussion from the comments of [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373865/2422776), it seems that the option to hide communities in the site settings misses the mark.

As far as I get it, this option exists for users who do not want to expose their involvement in a certain community (in the discussion I linked to, the idea was to use Stack Overflow to make yourself more appealing for potential employers in the field of software engineering without disclosing your involvement in subjects that may seem controversial, such as politics). However, as C. Helling pointed out in that discussion - hiding a community may remove it from your profile in a site, but it would still be visible in your network profile.

Doesn't this miss the point? Should a hidden community be hidden from the network profile too?

Comment: It is to a degree... The profile stops appearing in the "accounts" tab and the Network profile link at the top of the profile is no longer shown to other users. Perhaps the person was just confused because as the owner of the profile you still see the links? Or maybe they're referring to the fact that [content still appears there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299234/why-are-my-hidden-communities-visible-under-the-top-reputation-and-activit)?