# Why is a not-hidden community hidden on a user profile page?

Tags: support, bug, profile-page, user-accounts, hidden-communities

A user recently asked on the main Meta chat-board why the community section of [this user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14649843/carog?tab=profile) does not display their Stack Overflow account.

[image]

I initially just assumed that the user added the Stack Overflow community to the Hidden Communities in their profile.

[image]

Yet, for some reason, the ["view all" link](https://stackexchange.com/users/19988120/carog?tab=accounts) does include the Stack Overflow account too.

[image]

This is in contrast with my own profile which does not include communities that I have hidden on either list.

Based on recent comments

> It's not hidden. Now that I'm a moderator, I can see everyone's hidden communities in grey on SE, no matter if they belong to my site or not. Stack Overflow is white. (In addition to the other reasons it doesn't act like it's hidden.) – **Laurel** 12 hours ago

The Stack Overflow community apparently is not an hidden community. But then... what is the reason for it to be invisible in the communities panel?

Notice: [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299234/why-are-my-hidden-communities-visible-under-the-top-reputation-and-activit) does no longer seem to be related since apparently the affected user is not using the "hidden communities" feature.

Comment: It's not hidden. Now that I'm a moderator, I can see everyone's hidden communities in grey on SE, no matter if they belong to my site or not. Stack Overflow is white. (In addition to the other reasons it doesn't act like it's hidden.)

Comment: Might be a bug.

Comment: @Laurel thanks for the check, updated the question to reflect that.